# Symfony PdoSessionStorage Issues After Upgrading to 2.1

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I'm having some issues with my Symfony application after upgrading from 2.0.X to 2.1. The application was using PdoSessionStorage just fine before the upgrade. [The docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/pdo_session_storage.html) say that there are some differences in the config for PdoSessionStorage in 2.1 but I think that I was able to make those changes okay.

The problem that I'm seeing is that there is no data being added to the session_value(db_data_col) column in the session table. It is adding a new record for the current session but it's leaving the data empty.

Has anyone had this problem yet?

My config contains the following:

```
framework:
    session:
        handler_id:     session.handler.pdo
parameters:
    pdo.db_options:
        db_table:    session
        db_id_col:   session_id
        db_data_col: session_value
        db_time_col: session_time
services:
    pdo:
        class: PDO
        arguments:
            dsn:         "mysql:host=%database_host%;port=%database_port%;dbname=%database_name%"
            user:        %database_user%
            password:    %database_password%

    session.handler.pdo:
        class:     Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler
        arguments: [@pdo, %pdo.db_options%]
```

Comment: Have you tried to check the queries that are run on the db maybe using the profiler toolbar?

Comment: I took a look but I'm not seeing anything for the Session in the profiler. I did try dumping the value of $data in Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler::write but it's just an empty string

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After looking at the PdoSessionHandler.php code, I figured out that the code rely on the fact that the session_id is uniq. If you are like me and you created the session table based on this [article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/pdo_session_storage.html) it's not the case.

edit: in fact it is the case.. I don't know why it was not the case in my db

In my case to fix it, I had to empty the session table and make session_id field uniq

Comment: Hey Yann, thanks for the reply. I tried this but it doesn't seem to be working for me. Going to keep trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what was going on. We uncovered a bit of older code that was modifying the $_SESSION. S2.1 changes the keys that it uses in $_SESSION from "_symfony2" to "*sf2**"